# Flask con Ajax error tasks.forEach

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

Buenas estoy haciendo una app con `Flask` utilizando `Ajax` hago una consulta con peewee para obtener los datos el problema recae cuando intento agregar los datos desde JQuery me manda error en el forEach en Jquery todo se hace mediante una barra de busqueda para que muestre tareas pero no funciona.

HTML

```
 <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input name="sear" id="sear" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
  </div>
</nav>

    <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="card my-4" id="task-result">
        <div class="card-body">
          <!-- SEARCH -->
          <ul id="container"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Description</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tasks"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, redirect
from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict
from peewee import *
import json


db = MySQLDatabase('ejemplo', user='root', password='1234',host='localhost', port=3306)

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='Template')
app.secret_key = 'hin6bab8ge25*r=x&amp;+5$0kn=-#log$pt^#@vrqjld!^2ci@g*b'
class model(Model):
        class Meta:
            database = db

def create():
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([task])

class task(model):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    nombre = TextField()
    descripcion = TextField()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('Pruebas.html')

@app.route('/Ajax',methods=['POST'])
def Ajax():
    sear = request.form['sear']
    if(sear):
        u = task.select().where(task.nombre.contains(sear)).get()
        print(model_to_dict(u,backrefs=True))
        return json.dumps(model_to_dict(u,backrefs=True))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create()
    app.run(debug=True,port = 4500)
```

Jquery(Ajax)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('JQuery Works');
  $('#task-result').hide();
  $('#sear').keyup(function () {
    if($('#sear').val()){
      let sear = $('#sear').val();
      $.ajax({
          url: '/Ajax',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {sear},
          success: function (response) {
              console.log('gola');
              console.log(response);
              //let tasks = JSON.parse(response);
              let tmp = '';
              tasks.forEach(task =>{
                  tmp +=`<li>
                        $(task.nombre)
                    </li>`
              });
              $('#container').html(tmp);
              $('#task-result').show();
          }
      })
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner cual es el error exacto que te da? Y revisa que en ``<li>
                        $(task.nombre)
                    </li>`` estes usando comillas y no acentos.

Comment: El error que me sale en la consola de firefox es este con el foreach `TypeError: tasks.forEach is not a function``ya lo intente con la funcion $.each pero no me trae el valor lo marca indefinido

Answer (score 1):

Leyendo el error, y fijándome bien en el código, dentro del success de la llamada ajax tienes comentado este código `//let tasks = JSON.parse(response);` Por tanto estas tratando de hacer un foreach sobre una variable que no has inicializado.

Descomentalo y vuelve ha probar. Si te sigue sin funcionar, asegúrate de que response llega con datos y que el parse se hace correctamente.

Comment: Claro ese era el problema y mas aparte que no mande el jason como array lo mande como una cadena por eso era el error